# Android Fragment Transaction Animation Crashes If You Click While Animation is on Progress

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am new to using fragment animations and right now I am facing an issue. I tried adding animations to fragment transactions. They are working, however, when I try to click buttons while transaction is still in progress, app crashes. How do I avoid this? Here is my code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragmentMain);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Error:

```
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mts.wifisharetest, PID: 14140
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No host
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1194)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1189)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2001)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1976)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1051)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
10-09 14:35:23.212 14140-14140/com.mts.wifisharetest E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you test on simulator? Try again on real device with connectivity enable.

Comment: @EdwardBishop Did you ever figure out what might be causing this / a fix for this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this Code:**

```
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim);
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listFragment, new YourFragment());
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Fragment Starting Animation :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set>
    <objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="2000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
```

**Fragment Ending Animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set>
    <objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-2000"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
```

Hope it helps you for using the Transparent Fragment animations.